# ListBox.DisplayMember and Internal Properties

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, listbox, bindinglist

I am working on updating some class projects for a professor at my university. In my update process, I am building out examples the students can follow if they would like. However, I am hitting a small snag in the process.

Recently, I updated all of the important class properties to have an internal access modifier. By doing this, the ListBox I am using to display a property from said class with "Internal Properties" no longer displays the value, but instead the entire object path.

For example, I have the following class property:
`internal string firstName {get; set;}`

By using a `BindingList<Employee>` to bind the data to the list box, the `DisplayMember` for the listbox will be like "Path.to.value." instead of just displaying

If I switch the property back to being Public, this functionality works perfectly fine, but when it is labeled as internal, it is causing issues.

Employee fullName Property Definition

```
internal string fullName { get; set; }
```

Code implementation in my Form1.cs for handing all form events

```
BindingList<Employee> bd = new BindingList<Employee>();

lsbx_empList.DataSource = bd;
lsbx_empList.DisplayMember = "fullName";
```

Expected result is to display the "fullName" property, but actual results are displaying the object path to the fullName property.

Comment: Why did you set that property member to `internal` when you intend to use as a `public` member? *A common use of internal access is in component-based development because it enables a group of components to cooperate in a private manner without being exposed to the rest of the application code*.

Comment: The definition of Internal Access is exactly why I want the data to be labeled as internal. Once again, this is for a University project, and may not 100% accurately reflect industry, but instead is used to promote learning.

Comment: How do you propose to let a ListBox, a public component, to *cooperate in a private manner*? With *internal-external inheritance*? You can access the `internal` members only if you create an object that inherits from your `Employee` class. Another way is to expose it through a public property. e.g., `internal string FullName => this.ToString(); public override string ToString() => this.FirstName + (char)32 + this.LastName;` (assuming you also have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties). Now you can use `FullName` as `DisplayMember`. It make the property read-only, though.